# How to simulate COALESCE conditions in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Say I have the following:

```
SELECT    * 

FROM      Xyz 

WHERE     (@a IS NULL OR a = @a) AND
          (@b IS NULL OR b = @b) AND
          (@c IS NULL OR c = @c)
```

What I want to accomplish is to change the WHERE clause to use the conditions in a sort of `COALESCE` fashion where it would use the first condition that was not null or it ran out conditions.

In pseudo speak it would be something like:

```
WHERE    IF @a IS NOT NULL THEN
         (
             a = @a
         )
         ELSE IF @b IS NOT NULL THEN 
         (
             b = @b
         )
         ELSE IF @c IS NOT NULL THEN 
         (
             c = @c
         )
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You could use `CASE`.  `CASE` does not reliably provide short circuit evaluation in the presence of aggregation functions.  See [CASE / COALESCE won't always evaluate in textual order](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/690017/case-coalesce-wont-always-evaluate-in-textual-order) and [Aggregates Don't Follow the Semantics Of CASE](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/691535/aggregates-dont-follow-the-semantics-of-case).

Comment: @HABO also see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12941/does-sql-server-read-all-of-a-coalesce-function-even-if-the-first-argument-is-no/12945#12945 for a fun exception to the rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This will treat NULLs as wildcards:**

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE COALESCE(
  NULLIF(@a,a),
  NULLIF(@b,b),
  NULLIF(@c,c)
) IS NULL
```

**This will use the first non-null condition:**

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT id,value
  FROM (VALUES (1,a),(2,b),(3,c)) t1(id,value)
  INTERSECT
  SELECT TOP 1 id,comparator
  FROM (VALUES (1,@a),(2,@b),(3,@c)) t(id,comparator)
  WHERE comparator IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY id
)
```

Comment: Nice. I was trying to find a solution of this kind but eventually gave up (too soon, apparently).

Answer (score 4):

There may be a more elegant way, but this should respect the desired logic

```
where
(@a is not null and @a = a) or
(@a is null and @b is not null and @b = b) or
(@a is null and @b is null and @c is not null and @c = c)
```

which can be (a bit) simplified to:

```
where
(@a = a) or
(@a is null and @b = b) or
(@a is null and @b is null and @c = c)
```

Comment: Right, that's essentially what I want, but indeed, a more elegant way would be preferred, as I have more than 3 conditions, and that would get a bit wordy.

Comment: @CodeMaverick: I would worry about performance. With an `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` query hint the execution plan could include an `Index Seek` (if there are proper indexes).

Answer (score 3):

```
/* 
Since you are dynamically changing your condition you will need to 
use Dynamic sql and and build your query dynamically something like
this......
*/

CREATE TABLE Test_Dynamic (ID INT, A INT, B INT, C INT)
INSERT INTO Test_Dynamic VALUES
(1, 100, 1000, 10000),
(2, 200, 2000, 20000),
(3, 300, 3000, 30000),
(4, 400, 4000, 40000)

DECLARE @a INT, @b INT, @c INT;
SET @a = 100;
--SET @b = 1000;
--SET @c = 10000;

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql = N'SELECT * FROM  Test_Dynamic  WHERE 1 = 1 '

IF (@a IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
 SET @Sql = @Sql + N' AND A = @ar'
  IF (@b IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
     SET @Sql = @Sql + N' AND B = @br'
       IF (@c IS NOT NULL)
         BEGIN
         SET @Sql = @Sql + N' AND C = @cr'
         END   
    END
END

PRINT @Sql

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
                      ,N'@ar INT, @br INT, @cr INT'
                      ,@ar = @a
                      ,@br = @b
                      ,@cr = @c
```

Comment: That's definitely one way to go, but a way I was trying to avoid.

Comment: if @a is not null and @b is not null (for example), both conditions will be applied. So that's not the same as stopping after first non null variable.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus - That is true.  Good catch, I didn't even look at it since I didn't want to go the `sp_executesql` route.

Comment: By the way, I'm not the downvoter, as it could be easily changed to a valid if... else if... else solution

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Thanks for the pointer and please feel free to edit my answer, not bothered about the down vote :)

Comment: The dynamic query will not run because the `@a` or `@b` or `@c` will be undefined.

Comment: @AndriyM but if any of the these variables are not defined will any of the advised solution work ???

Comment: I am talking about the *dynamic* query that your script is building (and executing). The variables `@a`, `@b`, `@c` are defined in the scope of the main query, but not in the scope of the dynamic query.

Comment: Just replace the `SELECT * FROM Xyz` bit with `SELECT 1`, that'll make your script independent of the environment. Run it and [you'll see](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/27989).

Comment: @AndriyM thank you very much for the pointer really appreciate it :)

Comment: Oh, it's all right. But it would be great if you provided a fix for that issue in your answer. :)

Comment: I have added some test data and it works fine. I dont know if im still missing something but to me it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the result of a boolean expression as a value in SQL Server, but you could replace it with a logical `1`/`0`, something like this:

```
WHERE
  CASE
              WHEN @a IS NOT NULL AND a = @a THEN 1
    ELSE CASE WHEN @b IS NOT NULL AND b = @b THEN 1
    ELSE CASE WHEN @c IS NOT NULL AND c = @c THEN 1
  END END END = 1
```

The above could also be rearranged like this (perhaps some people would find the logic clearer this way):

```
WHERE
  CASE
    WHEN @a IS NOT NULL AND a = @a THEN 1
    ELSE
      CASE
        WHEN @b IS NOT NULL AND b = @b THEN 1
        ELSE
          CASE
            WHEN @c IS NOT NULL AND c = @c THEN 1
          END
      END
  END = 1
```

Comment: This isn't the perfect solution, but it's definitely the closest so far.  Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, glad I could help! But your "so far" seems to imply that you have expectations to get other, possibly better, suggestions in the future. I might very well be wrong there, but if not, it might be a good idea to unaccept my answer to keep the question open.